# XML to HTML tag conversion

Tags: java, html, regex, xml

I have a String with XML tags within.

```
<PERSON>Obama</PERSON> is the current <POSITION>President</POSITION> of <LOCATION>United States of America<LOCATION>
```

I want to convert those tags to the form

```
<p><span style="background-color: #99cc00;"><a style="background-color: #99cc00;" title="PERSON" href="http://usa.com">OBAMA</a></span> is the current <span style="background-color: #99cc00;"><a style="background-color: #99cc00;" title="POSITION" href="http://usa.com">President</a></span> of <span style="background-color: #99cc00;"><a style="background-color: #99cc00;" title="LOCATION" href="http://usa.com">United States of America</a></span></p>
```

The problem here is to replace the XML TAGs with HTML tags (most of the things in the HTML are static like, background color, href etc.. )

Do I have to use a XML parser to actually achieve this?. Can a simple regex do the job (I'm using java). Any pointer to this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to parse the string. and search the correct locations.

```
String person -> cut the string between <Person> and </Person>
String desc1 = cut between </Person> and <Position>
```

...
etc

```
String.format("<p><span style="background-color: #99cc00;"><a style="background-color: #99cc00;" title="PERSON" href="http://usa.com">%s</a></span> %s <span style="background-color: #99cc00;"><a style="background-color: #99cc00;" title="POSITION" href="http://usa.com">President</a></span> %s <span style="background-color: #99cc00;"><a style="background-color: #99cc00;" title="LOCATION" href="http://usa.com">%s</a></span></p>"
,person, desc1, position, desc2, location)
```